# Using OpenGL Version 3+ to render text / UI

Tags: c++, opengl

I was looking for a library that uses OpenGL 3+ to render text / UI controls. Are there any examples / free libraries (preferably LGPL, MIT, etc) that demonstrate how this can be done.

I do not like to use GLUT and last I checked, FTGL did not use OpenGL 3.

Comment: Why would you use OpenGL to render text and UI controls?

Comment: to build apps such as these : http://www.cegui.org.uk/wiki/index.php/Main_Page

Comment: @jalf: To gain the ultimate kind of plattform independence. FYI: :Blender draws its whole UI using OpenGL – however this requires a very large number of hacks and special treatment for corner cases.

Comment: http://www.lighthouse3d.com/very-simple-libs/vsfl/ is an example that helps you draw text.

Comment: @datenwolf: you have a strange notion of "platform independence". It's so independent it will only run on desktop computers with a DX10+-class GPU and an up-to-date OpenGL driver. Right. Windows RT only has DirectX, and other mobile devices generally have OpenGL ES, but not "vanilla" OpenGL. Windows ships with GL2.1 (or is it 1.4?) drivers, as I recall. It is certainly a *kind* of platform independence, but there's nothing "ultimate" about it.

Comment: I am still not convinced that there is no library that does what I am looking for !

Comment: @jalf: If the application requires OpenGL-3 anyway, for example because it's a game or a 3D modeler, then why not reuse it for GUI rendering? The application won't work w/o OpenGL-3 anyway then.

Comment: Questions of the form "Find me a library that does X" are not allowed on Stack Overflow. We are not a Google replacement.

Comment: @datenwolf: I never said it didn't make sense to use OpenGL to render these things *in an application which already uses OpenGL*. But you're moving the goalpost. Your last comment claimed that it was "the ultimate kind of platform independence". It is not.

Comment: @jalf: TBH I was thinking about that very corner case. But you're right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if [SFML](http://www.sfml-dev.org) uses OpenGL 3+ for rendering text, but I do know that using it is more rewarding than GLUT. It can output text onto the window with the `sf::Text` class. Check out the documentation for the 2.0 version. Also, license states it is free to use "as-is", only to credit the author. And the most important thing it is portable.

Also there is a tutorial for a [CEGUI](http://www.sfml-dev.org/wiki/en/tutorials/cegui) library combined with SFML to create GUI elements. It could be good enough, I have not tried it unfortunately.